# Openshift server not able to pick up CSS in subfolder

Tags: jsf, outputstylesheet

I have placed css files in sub folder which are not loaded.

```
application
 --resource
  ---bootstrap
     ----css
      -----bootstrap.min.css
```

The tag used is

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css\bootstrap.min.css" library="bootstrap" />
```

This is rendered as

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND" />
```

I have deployed the application in openshift. It is working correctly in my local

The server is same in both places "wildfly -10".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11988415/1391249

Comment: Why are you using \ instead of / as path separator while the / is shown in every single sane web development related tutorial/book/resource?

Comment: Changed the path seperator and deployed to open shift working correctly. Thanks BalusC